# How to monitor Samba "LDAP" traffic?

Tags: samba, ldap

I have Samba running as AD Domain Controller, I want to debug the LDAP connections coming to my Samba LDAP server.

I tried to raise the log level, but still I see no useful information except the very verbose output.

Basically I want to see everything happening, binding, authentication, filters, etc.

How can this be achieved?

I tried this:

```
log level = 4
```

and

```
log level = 1 auth_audit:3 auth_json_audit:3
```

but still I see no LDAP connections, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: See https://www.wireshark.org Install `wireshark`. It's the tool for monitoring network traffic.

Comment: @waltinator I excluded wireshark in the beginning because I did not know if it going to show me what is happening inside Samba, for example the details of exceptions or errors. Would it?

To debug communications between servers, probably tcpdump redirected to wireshark on different host rather than wireshark alone, which probably cannot be run on CLI-only servers.

Comment: Unable to test this at the moment but could you try to raise the log level for the `ldb` subsystem specifically?